# FontAwesome: icon-4x no worky

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm using FontAwesome via their CDN:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But I cannot get the icons to render anything larger than icon-large, so this:

```
<i class="icon-laptop icon-4x"></i>
```

Renders as the default tiny icon. I have no other code impeding it, and can't figure out why its not working. If I do this:

```
<i class="icon-laptop icon-large"></i>
```

I get the large icon, but I want the HUGE icon! Help!

Comment: Ok, It just noticed if I take the icons out of the icon-stack, the 4x works.  So I can either stack them, or blow them up, but not both? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question should be : "How to change the size of a stack of icons".

The thing is, if you want to change the size of a stack of icons, you have to add the "icon-4x" class to  the stack and not to the icons directly.

For example :

```
<span class="icon-stack icon-4x">
    <i class="icon-circle-blank icon-stack-base"></i>
    <i class="icon-laptop"></i>
</span>
```